# Schema - Returning all errros

Tags: python

I would like to know if it's possible to get all errors from [schema](https://github.com/keleshev/schema).

Let's say that i have following schema and data:

```
SCHEMA=Schema({"name": str, "age": int})

data={"name": 1, "age": "2"}
```

Then `SCHEMA.validate(data)` would throw an exception only for "name". The next error would only occur after the first one would have been corrected.

My first idea was, to correct the error with a "dummy" key:value pair, which would pass the check and to rerun the validation recursively until no other exception is thrown and gather all errors in the process. But i am not sure about whether or not that would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at https://github.com/keleshev/schema/blob/master/schema.py#L149 there is no way to do this. The first error it gets it will throw an Exception. Recursion is probably your only bet to get it working with this tool

Comment: I see. Should have looked into the source myself, before asking. Anyways, thank you very much!